# How to let eslint react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rule know that the return value of a custom hook is invariant?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

When you call one of the "builtin" hook, the `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` rule is smart enough to recognize that some return values are guaranteed by React to be invariant. This is the case for state updaters and dispatchers returned by `useState` and `useReducer` hooks.

In this first example, the call to `useCallback` does not need to list the state setter as a dependency:

```js
export const Example1 = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date())

  const resetDate = useCallback(() => {
    setDate(new Date())
  }, []) // No need to list any dependency here. No eslint warning.

  return (
    <>
      Date: {date.toISOString()} <button onClick={resetDate}>Reset</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

But in the second example, where the setter is returned by a custom hook, it is required.

```js
const useDateState = (initialValue: Date) => {
  return useState(initialValue)
}

export const Example2 = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useDateState(new Date())

  const resetDate = useCallback(() => {
    setDate(new Date())
  }, []) // ESLint complains: React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'setDate'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

  return (
    <>
      Date: {date.toISOString()} <button onClick={resetDate}>Reset</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Is there a way to tell the eslint rule that the setter returned by my custom hook will not change and that it does not need to list it as a dependency? This would help remove some code.

Note: I have read [the React FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies), [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58038252/react-eslint-eslint-plugin-react-hooks-shows-incorrect-missing-dependency) and I understand that there is no performance cost to adding a dependency that will not change.

But since this behavior is available with the built-in hooks, I want to know if there is a way to get the same for a custom hook.

Comment: See also this GitHub issue which discusses the same problem: https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/1889